# Using a block to find values matching criteria

Tags: ruby, block

To me this makes perfect sense:

```
triple = dice.collect {|value| if (dice.count(value) >= 3)} ---> Syntax error
```

OR

```
triple = dice.collect {|value| dice.count(value) >= 3} ----> Array of true/false
```

I want the value of the number, not the true or falsity of dice.count(). I know there *must* be a simple way of doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want [`Array#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000251), not [`Array#collect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000247) (also known as [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000249)).

`collect/map` will take each `value` and put the results of your block into an array. This is why you're seeing an array of true/false.

`select` will take each `value`, and return it as a member of an array if the block evaluates to `true`:

```
triple = dice.select{ |value| dice.count(value) >= 3 }
```

Comment: i think you meant to write "select" on the last line.

Comment: Whoops, yes, I meant `select`.

Answer (score 1):

Your block needs to return whatever it is you want in the final array.

```
triple = dice.collect {|value| 
  if dice.count(value) >= 3
    dice.count(value)
  end
}
```

Note that this will return `nil` for elements < 3 (though you can add an `else` to return 0 or something). If you only want elements that match your query, you'll need to use `dice.select()`

Comment: Sad, the cost of dice.count(value) is indeterminate and likely could be expensive, and in your block it gets invoked twice. Just use "select" instead of "collect".

Comment: Indeed, select is better, but only if you don't need the array to contain `nil` or some other determinate value. In his case, he doesn't, but could have.

Answer (score 1):

As for your first code snippet,

```
triple = dice.collect {|value| THE_CODE_BLOCK_STARTS_HERE }
```

Thus, `if (dice.count(value) >= 3)` is an incomplete `if` statement. That's why you get syntax error.